# How can I do an onchange form submit without refreshing the page after selecting from a dropdown list?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My page keeps refreshing when I select an item from a listbox. I'm new to Ajax and still learning from it. Here's my code I want to make Ajax code for this one.

```
<form id="myform" action="home_log.php" method="post">
    <label1>Room Type:*</label1> 
    <select name="roomtype" onchange="this.form.submit();"> 
        <option value="Standard Room A">Standard Room A</option>
        <option value="Standard Room B">Standard Room B</option>
        <option value="Deluxe Room">Deluxe Room</option>
    </select>
</form><br>
<label1>Room Number:*</label1>
<div id="form_output">
<?php
    $roomtype = isset($_POST['roomtype']) ? $_POST['roomtype'] : '';
    echo "<select>";
    include_once 'includes/dbh-inc.php';
    $result = $conn->query("select RoomName from tblroom_sample where RoomType='".$roomtype."'");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          unset($roomtype);
          $RoomName = $row['RoomName']; 
          echo '<option value="'.$RoomName.'">'.$RoomName.'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
                type: "GET",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#form_output").html(data);
                },
                error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have editted the post, can you assist me with this?

Comment: Err, your listbox is not inside the `<form></form>` tags so will never get a value picked up from it

Comment: Is it that page refreshes when you change the `select` or when you click the `button`?    If it's the button, change the button to `type='button'` and the handler to `button.click` (instead of form submit) and make necessary changes (ie get the url from the button's parent form).  Looks like your form is submitting despite the `e.preventDefault()`.  There's lots of Qs+As for this on SO.

Comment: Just noticed you have two `select`s - didn't see the other one hidden in all the obfusticated php hieroglyphics.  Which one is causing the problem?

Comment: oh sorry, an onchange was supposed to be in the select tag

Comment: Because ALL this code is in ONE FILE, each time you run the AJAX the whole page will be returned

Comment: @RiggsFolly but then the whole page would be duplicated in `form_output` each time (nested) - doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Think of an ajax call as a call to a subroutine. Seperate the AJAX called code into a seperate file and only return (echo) what you want as the result of that subroutine call. Remember everything that would normally be sent back to the browser will be sent as the result of the ajax call, even the HTML

Comment: @freedomn-m Yea I wondered if it was that simple, but the OP does not necessarily describe the error situation very well so I thought I would have a punt at that

Comment: Remove the `onchange="this.form.submit();"` and add it as jquery event: `$("#myForm>select").change(function() { ajaxPostFunction(); });` then move the ajax code to `ajaxPostFunction()` (suitably named for course).   (and change the button to `type=button` as well and have its click handler call the same code).  ie don't allow the form to submit/post at all, take control

Comment: I think what's wrong is my ajax code